From list of lists, keep only subsets of predefined list
Using Ansible, from a list of lists I need to keep only elements with lists that are a subset of a predefined list.
Having the following predefined list
allowed_roles:
  - member
  - read
  - update

from this original input list:
user_roles:
  - name: alice
    roles:
      - admin
      - member
      - read
  - name: Bob
    roles:
      - member
      - read
  - name: Camille
    roles:
      - member
      - update

I need to remove alice because its roles are not a subset of allowed_roles. Needed result is :
user_roles:
  - name: Bob
    roles:
      - member
      - read
  - name: Camille
    roles:
      - member
      - update

I tried :
{{ user_roles | selectattr('roles', 'is', subset(allowed_roles) }}

and other variations but no luck.

I was impatient. The second argument of selectattr should be the test plugin. The solution is :
{{ user_roles | selectattr('roles', 'subset', allowed_roles) }}

